# cy.click() can only be called on a single element

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to select two buttons one after one , a Delete button and after that the Yes popup confirmation ,by this:

```
cy.get('.btn-danger').last().click();
cy.get('.btn-primary').click();
```

But i got this error:

**CypressError: cy.click() can only be called on a single element. 
Your subject contained 2 elements. 
Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element.**

Comment: I wanted to put an upvote here, unfortunately down vote pressed!.. How to recover that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think there are two buttons with `btn-primary` class in your popup DOM (yes and cancel?). Try to access the yes confirmation button by its id or something. Or if you're sure about the order, then use `.first()` or `.last()` like you used for clicking the delete button.

Answer (score 6):

Another method is with `.eq(index)` assuming you have array of two buttons `[0, 1]` and last being `1`

```
cy.get('.btn-danger').eq(0).click();
cy.get('.btn-primary').eq(1).click();
```

Check for documentation [Eq function](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq#Syntax).

Answer (score 1):

I've written like this :

```
describe('handling Iframes', function () {
    it("cy iframe", () => {
      
cy.get('iframe').its('0.contentDocument.body').find("span[class='ag-group-contracted']").last().click();
  
         })
})
```